# Property Name to Lambda Expression C#

Tags: c#, lambda

How can I convert a property name to Lambda expression in C#?

Like this:  `string prop = "Name";` to (`p => p.Name`)

```
public class Person{
    public string Name{ get; set; } 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: A lambda expression is not a type. Do you mean a delegate or an expression tree? And of *exactly* what type?

Comment: I don't understand your question... You want to turn a variable declaration into a property access expression?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Converting a property name to Lambda does not really make sense. Add some context.

Comment: I have a Expression<Func<T, object>> param in a function, and I have only the property name, so I need to "transform" the property name into a Expression.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using expression trees you can generate the lambda expression.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetPropertySelector<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var property = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
    //return the property as object
    var conv = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conv, new ParameterExpression[] { arg });
    return exp;
}
```

for `Person` you can call it like:

```
var exp = GetPropertySelector<Person>("Name");//exp: x=>x.Name
```

Comment: This isn't reflection

Comment: This works only for string. Is there a way to make the Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, string>> generic? I've tryied Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, object>> but didn't work.

Comment: I've change it to support generics.

Comment: I would say: "You can use **expression trees**" :D

Comment: Some part of Expression tree is in fact based on Reflection. Looks like the `conv` is redundant here, you can just pass `property` in the `Expression.Lambda` instead of `conv` (tested and it works that way).

Comment: @Hopeless: Convert is required for value types, like int. Without it this exception is thrown: "Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'"

Answer (score 1):

A lambda is just an anonymous function. You can store lambdas in delegates just like regular methods. I suggest you try making "Name" a property.

`public string Name { get { return p.Name; } }`

If you really want a lambda, use a delegate type such as Func.

`public Func<string> Name = () => p.Name;`

Comment: well yes, since it doesn't have a name to define its location.

Comment: And what about expression trees? Are them delegates too? :P

Comment: To be fair, I'm not familiar with expression trees (if you're talking about Linq's Expression class), but I don't think it inherits from either Delegate or is a delegate type.

Comment: They're not delegates. They can compile to delegates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86808/discussion-between-philippe-pare-and-matias-fidemraizer).