# Property name to lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, dependency-injection

I have some code which I would like to refactor, but I don't know how to do it.  The code in question repeats itself, except for an expression which varies.

The code:

```
Expression<Func<SearchModel, bool>> first = null;
if (first == null)
{
    if (equal && not)
        first = c1 => c1.Address.PostalCode != newTerm;
    else if (equal)
        first = c1 => c1.Address.PostalCode == newTerm;
    else if (not)
        first = c1 => !c1.Address.PostalCode.Contains(newTerm);
    else
        first = c1 => c1.Address.PostalCode.Contains(newTerm);
}
else
{
    if (equal && not)
        first = first.Or(c1 => c1.Address.PostalCode != newTerm);
    else if (equal)
        first = first.Or(c1 => c1.Address.PostalCode == newTerm);
    else if (not)
        first = first.Or(c1 => !c1.Address.PostalCode.Contains(newTerm));
    else
        first = first.Or(c1 => c1.Address.PostalCode.Contains(newTerm));
}
```

`equal` and `not` are Boolean values.

This code is repeated several times, except that `c1.Address.PostalCode` could be `c1.Address.City`, or even `c1.User.PhoneNumber`.

Can I somehow refactor this so that I can use a method and inject the `c1.Address.PostalCode`? Something like this:

```
if (equal && not)
    first = c1 => <variable> != newTerm;
...
else if (not)
    first = c1 => !<variable>.Contains(newTerm);
```

It looks like this post is what I'm looking for:

[Property Name to Lambda Expression C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948269/property-name-to-lambda-expression-c-sharp)

But I need to go a little further, because the Address property is a class itself, which of course has properties, one of which is PostalCode.

Comment: You could use reflection but you would need to have some more if statement if the property type is a collection or not because of the contains.

Comment: @Franck The code expects the property value to be a string, not a collection.  It's doing a string contains check.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the link.  Indeed that's what I was looking for. (It would have helped had I known what to search!)  I've managed to pass my expression into a method, but I'm unsure what to do with it.  I'm passing a `Expression<Func<SearchModel, object>>` into the method.  When I debug and watch the value, it shows it is `{smodel => smodel.User.ContactLastName}`, but I don't know how to use that in my code `first = c1 => c1.User.ContactLastName == newTerm`.

Comment: There's an example right in the answer in the duplicate of how to use the method.

Comment: @Servy I don't see it.  I've copied all your code, using the same variable names, and I'm passing "magic" to my method.  I don't see how to use "magic" once inside the method though.

Comment: @MarcLevesque You assign it to `first`.

Comment: @Servy That won't work because first is type `Expression<Func<SearchModel, bool>>` and magic is type `Expression<Func<SearchModel, object>>`.

Comment: @MarcLevesque The reason you're calling compose is to turn your mapping from a search model to a property value and your mapping from a property value to a boolean into a mapping from a search model to a boolean.  So the return value of `Compose` *will* be an `Expression<Func<SearchModel, bool>>` for you.